# In SQLite, how do you show groups with a count of zero?

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite, how do you show groups with a count of zero?

i.e It looks like:

> AGE RANGE: ------------ COUNT:
>
> 18 - 25------------------------       16
>
> 26 - 30------------------------- 5
>
> 31 - 35 ------------------------ 2

But I want it to look like:

> AGE RANGE: ------------ COUNT:
>
> 18 - 25------------------------       16
>
> 26 - 30------------------------- 5
>
> 31 - 35 ------------------------ 2
>
> 36+ ---------------------------- 0

Many Thanks

Z

Comment: If you're asking us to help you change a query that doesn't do what you want, then you need to show us the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be overinterpreting, but it seems like you're probably doing something like:

```
SELECT range, COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY range
```

In order for a `range` to appear in the output, it must be represented in the input table, so you can never have a zero count appear in such a query.

But, if you have *another* table that lists the ranges, whether they appear in `mytable` or not, then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT ranges.range, COUNT(mytable.range) 
    FROM ranges LEFT JOIN mytable ON ranges.range=mytable.range
    GROUP BY ranges.range;
```

Comment: What about having only one table?